# python install module manually raspberry pi

Tags: python, module, raspberry-pi

I have to install a module insteon.py manually.

So I copied the module in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.

When I try to import the module insteon.py, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    from insteon import Insteon
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/insteon.py", line 25, in <module>
    config = configuration.loadConfig()
AttributeError: Configuration instance has no attribute 'loadConfig'
```

Comment: can you post the contents of `insteon.py` ? looks very different from that one: https://github.com/seanhagen/Python-Exhibition-Movie-Player/blob/master/insteon.py. And are there other python modules in the same directory that you should copy too?

Comment: And can you explain why you can't install it using the proper installation methods?

Comment: I am new here on this forum and I tried to sent the pythonscript but I cannot send the script. I tried <pre><code> and then past my script in to it but it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps the insteon module depends on other modules, which weren't installed properly because you installed insteon manually.

Comment: Fixed formatting of trace-back.

Answer (score 0):

if you would you can download the script here

https://github.com/bynds/makevoicedemo